# Использование Yii. Включение gii

Tags: php, yii

Приветствую всех вошедших

Тема близка к биткоду, но все же это Хэшкодовская тема. Сейчас развелось людей, которые в место того, что бы писать - берут готовенькое и настраивают под себя. Собственно я решил стать таким и первый раз поставил php фреймворк Yii (с офф. сайта).

1. скачать/установить по инструкции. Ok.
2. В моем случае http://localhost/onechance/index.php - зашел, работает. Ok.
3. пытаюсь попасть в gii - index.php?r=gii или index.php/gii - ошибка 404. не работает

Конечно гугл в помощь, все дела, но там написано, это проблема адреса - красивого и не красивого (index.php?r=gii или index.php/gii), я это ест-но учел

Может ли кто посоветовать, что исправить во фреймворке Yii, что бы он нашел нужную страничку? Может там нужно до установить, или до настроить?

p.s. Вообще, свою страницу, он по любому должен находить. Даже как то странно

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в файле конфигурации. Всё сделали по инструкции?

Comment: @Zhukov Roman, да, сейчас, второй день, понять не могу, где не так. Вообще сложно где то на косячить, если просто ставишь.

Comment: Если кто может то киньте мне свой файл конфигурации, посмотрю, что выйдет. А то тема сам знаю, на подобии как открыть пакетик с чаем 8-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'modules'=>array(
              'gii'=>array(
                      'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
                      'password'=>'passwd',
                      'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
                        ),

                ),
```

Есть такое в конфиге?

а так

```
http://localhost/onechance/gii
```

Comment: да. у меня пароль '12345678'. Ест-но если поменять на 'passwd' - ничего не меняется. страницы по умолчанию работают, что странно (Home/About/Contact/Login)

Comment: попробовал /gii - серая страница дэнвера, где Not Found и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Так как в качестве веб-сервера я использую виртуальную машину, нужно было добавить в список ipFilters айпи интерфейса с которого я захожу на веб-сервер. т.е.:

```
 'gii'=>array(
         'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
         'password'=>'passwd',
         'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1','192.168.19.1'),
  ),
```